# Anyone know why my pushbutton is always returning HIGH?

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, c++

Been trying to figure this out for a couple hours, despite how ridiculously simple it should be. I have no idea why it's always returning 1, even when i'm pushing the button. Fritzing sketch:
[image]

My code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define button 3

Servo myservo1;
Servo myservo2;
Servo myservo3;

char incomingByte = "";
int timer;
int timer2;
int interval;
int numservo = 3;
int press1 = 90;
int letup = 0;
int val = 0;
  
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo1.attach(9);
  myservo1.write(0);
  myservo2.attach(7);
  myservo2.write(0);
  myservo3.attach(5);
  myservo3.write(0);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  val = digitalRead(button);
  Serial.println(val);
  
  //checkerthing();

    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      incomingByte = Serial.read();
      timer  = incomingByte - '0';
      Serial.println(timer);
      timer2 = timer * 60;
      interval = timer2/numservo;
    


     motor1_control(press1, letup, interval);
     checkerthing();
     motor2control(press1, letup, interval);
     checkerthing();
     motor3control(press1, letup, interval);
     checkerthing();
     
      
      
     timer = 0;
     timer2 = 0;
     interval = 0;
    }

   

  }
    

void checkerthing() {
  val = digitalRead(button);
  if (val == LOW){ 
    Serial.println("Stopped");
    timer = 0;
    timer2 = 0;
    interval = 0;
    
  }
  if (val == HIGH){
    Serial.println("Still going");
  }

}
void motor1_control(int angle, int originalangle, int lengthoftime){
    myservo1.write(angle);
    delay(1000);
    myservo1.write(originalangle);
    delay(lengthoftime * 1000);
    
}

void motor2control(int angle, int originalangle, int lengthoftime){
    myservo1.write(angle);
    delay(1000);
    myservo1.write(originalangle);
    delay(lengthoftime * 1000);
    
}

void motor3control(int angle, int originalangle, int lengthoftime){
    myservo1.write(angle);
    delay(1000);
    myservo1.write(originalangle);
    delay(lengthoftime * 1000);
    
}
```

Basically, the point of this is to have the servo motors go off at specific intervals as given by the user in the serial monitor. The button exists so that the user can restart the timer at any point in the code. But the problem is, I can't even get it to register the button being pushed. It always returns "HIGH", which leads me to believe there's something wrong with the circuits. I've tried using some different methods, but no luck. Can anyone tell me what the issue here is?

Edit: ...I hadn't pushed the pushbutton all the way into the breadboard. I'm gonna go cry in the corner for a bit. And then get back to coding I guess lol. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Is your breadboard one of the "split power rail" variety?

Comment: @Majenko no, it's a full power one

Comment: Well, if your real schematic is the same as the drawing then it should work.

Comment: Hade you checked you're using the correct terminals on the push button and it's making proper contact with the breadboard ?

Comment: What Bra1n said. I have to check those 4-lead pushbuttons every... single... time... because they're like Micro USB connectors; takes three tries to get the orientation right. Check continuity to make sure you're using the correct leads.

Comment: @Bra1n Oh god, I hadn't pushed the button in all the way. Ugh. Thank you.

Comment: @Crystal For those pushbuttons I flatten the leads; they ship with a "bump" which is great for PCBs, not so much for breadboards--squoosh 'em with pliers.

Comment: For people with trouble with those switches, I've seen it suggested to just always connect them by opposite (diagonal) corners.

Comment: @DaveNewton To be honest, all USB connectors have 3 sides...

Comment: you have INPUT_PULLUP so it should return HIGH if the button doesn't connect the pin to ground

Comment: You can try to ise a simple wire to pull the pin down to ground (connecting it to GND on the arduino board); if it works, then it's the wiring or the button, if it doesn't it's something else.

Comment: "I hadn't pushed the button in all the way." - You can write this as an answer and accept it. That will show that it has been solved, plus it will keep the question from being resurrected forEVER, waiting for an accepted answer that's never going to arrive.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 3):

Hadn't pushed the button all the way in lol

Comment: it has happened to me. sometimes, I had forgotten to power on UNO or connect USB!!